# XML sections to DataTable

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, dataset

I have an XML file that I need to load into a DataSet.  The file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<computers>
    <computer name="laptop">
        <role roleId="1" roleName="Supervisor" />
        <role roleId="2" roleName="Psuedo Pilot 1" />
        <role roleId="3" roleName="Psuedo Pilot 2" />
    </computer>
    <computer name="triplescreen">
       <role roleId="1" roleName="Tower Controllers" />
       <role roleId="2" roleName="Final Controllers" />
       <role roleId="3" roleName="Approach/Arrival" />
    </computer>
</computers>
```

I can read it into a DataSet like so:

```
string xmlFile = string.Format(@"{0}\configuration.xml", Environment.CurrentCirectory);
DataSet xmlDataSet = new DataSet("XML DataSet");
xmlDataSet.ReadXml(xmlFile);
```

But when I step through the code and look at what tables are in the DataSet, I only `computer` and `role` in the Table dropdown:

[image]

I am trying to get the DataSet to have a Table for each 'computer' of a specific name.